# template ctor type deduction does not work (no matching constructor for initialization of ...) with function<> argument

Tags: c++

I have this example (where I want to add a template overloaded constructor to class `C`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Msg {
public:
    void parse(const string &s) {
        x = int(s[0]);
    }
    int x = 0;
};
class C {
public:
    C(function<void(const string &)> cb)
        : cb_(cb)
    {}
    template<typename TMsg>
    C(function<void(const TMsg &)> cb)
        : C([&, cb](const string &s) {
                TMsg m; m.parse(s); cb(m);
          })
    {}
    void test() {
        cb_("foo");
    }
    function<void(const string &)> cb_;
};
void cb1(const string &s) {
    cout << "cb1: " << s << endl;
}
void cb2(const Msg &msg) {
    cout << "cb2: Msg{x=" << msg.x << "}" << endl;
}
int main() {
    C c1(&cb1), c2(&cb2); c1.test(); c2.test();
    return 0;
}
```

which gives this compiler error (clang++ 9.1):

```
test_func_arg_overload.cpp:37:17: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'C'
    C c1(&cb1), c2(&cb2); c1.test(); c2.test();
                ^  ~~~~
test_func_arg_overload.cpp:12:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not
      viable: no known conversion from 'void (*)(const Msg &)' to 'C' for 1st argument
class C {
      ^
test_func_arg_overload.cpp:12:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: no known conversion from 'void (*)(const Msg &)' to 'const C' for 1st argument
class C {
      ^
test_func_arg_overload.cpp:14:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
      'void (*)(const Msg &)' to 'function<void (const std::__1::string &)>' (aka 'function<void (const
      basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > &)>') for 1st argument
    C(function<void(const string &)> cb)
    ^
test_func_arg_overload.cpp:18:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void
      (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against 'void (*)(const Msg &)'
    C(function<void(const TMsg &)> cb)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a way to fix it other than making `C` a template class?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to cast the function pointer to the right type. This should work:

```
using f_t = std::function<void(const Msg &)>;
C c2(static_cast<f_t>(&cb2));
```

The problem is, that without the cast, you are providing function pointer, which should be automatically converted to `std::function<>` That would work if you had a  constructor overload for the exact type, as you do with the first example.

But in the second case, the overload resolution does not match the templated version, since the types do not match and the type deduction is not performed.

Answer (score 1):

lambda and function pointer doesn't match with `std::function`.

You can change your code to

```
template <typename F,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::string,
                                        std::decay_t<arg1_trait_t<F>>>::value, int> = 0>
C(F cb)
    : cb_(cb)
{}
template <typename F,
          std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::string,
                                         std::decay_t<arg1_trait_t<F>>>::value, int> = 0>
C(F cb) : C([cb](const string &s) {
        std::decay_t<arg1_trait_t<F>> m;
        m.parse(s);
        cb(m);
      })
{}
```

with

```
template <typename T> struct arg1_trait : arg1_trait<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename Ret, typename Arg>
struct arg1_trait<Ret (*) (Arg)> : arg1_trait<Ret (Arg)> {};

template <typename Ret, class C, typename Arg>
struct arg1_trait<Ret (C::*) (Arg)> : arg1_trait<Ret (Arg)> {};

template <typename Ret, class C, typename Arg>
struct arg1_trait<Ret (C::*) (Arg) const> : arg1_trait<Ret (Arg)> {};

template <typename Ret, typename Arg>
struct arg1_trait<Ret (Arg)>
{
    using type = Arg;   
};

template <typename T>
using arg1_trait_t = typename arg1_trait<T>::type;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ff99ef8ca4c45c3)